# Code to auto expire posts after 30 days

Tags: posts, functions

I've tried the plugins that are available in the Wordpress plugins section but they seem to fail miserably. Initially, I used Auto Post Expire By User Role which worked for a time, but for some reason now it doesn't.

What I want is to add a code in functions.php that will automatically set as drafts posts which are 30 days older than their published date.

I have the following code but don't know if this is the one that I should be using. Is this correct and if not, what is the correct form?

```
function expire_posts() {
global $wpdb;
$daystogo = "30";
$sql = "UPDATE wp_posts SET `post_status` = 'draft' WHERE `post_type` = 'post' AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), `post_date`) > '$daystogo')";
}

add_action('wp_head', 'expire_posts');
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some issues with your query

```
$daystogo = "30";

$sql =
"UPDATE {$wpdb->posts}
SET post_status = 'draft'
WHERE (post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish')
AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), post_date) > %d";

$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( $sql, $daystogo ) );
```

You do not want to untrash trashed posts by declaring them as draft, right? And you really do not want to make every automated saved version (post_status = inherit) a draft. So only select published posts.

Use `$wpdb-prepare()` for **EVERY** query.

(Edit: Every query that has variable inputs, that is. Don't use prepare for entirely static queries that have no variable inputs.)

Use the `WPDB` class variables instead of the plain table name `$wpdb->posts` instead of `wp_posts`. See the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Tables).

Test your query first before code them. Use something like an [MySQL frontend](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql%20frontend) or [MySQL-Admin](http://www.mysql-admin.org/). In your sql-query, there is a `)` at the end where no one should be.

Answer (score 1):

You just declared the query, but you didn't execute it!

```
function expire_posts() {
  global $wpdb;
  $daystogo = "30";
  $sql = "UPDATE wp_posts SET `post_status` = 'draft' WHERE `post_type` = 'post' AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), `post_date`) > '$daystogo')";
  $wpdb->query( $sql );
}
```

Don't forget to always [prepare your queries](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks).

It would also be a good idea to use the [`wp_cron()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron) to run the code at regular time inverval(eg once a day). When hooking to `wp_head`, the query will run each time a user visits a page.

Comment: No, not the Transients API. Use a [wp_cron()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron)

Comment: Yeah, cron is a better alternative

Comment: `wp_cron()` might not be the best option as it is executed only when a visitor open the website. `Standard cron jobs` will be a better option here which is set to be executed once a day to update all posts expired.